# Force update GUI in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am writing an app in kivy which does cpu-heavy calculations at launch. I want the app to display what it's doing at the moment along with the progress, however, since the main loop is not reached yet, it just displays empty white screen until it finishes working. Can I force kivy to update the interface?

Basically I'm looking for kivy's equivalent of Tkinter's `root.update()`

I could create a workaround by defining a series of functions with each calling the next one through `Clock.schedule_once(nextFunction, 1)`, but that would be very sloppy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using threads here?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the question of whether you should be using threading or something instead (which possibly you should), the answer is just that you should move your cpu calculations to somewhere else. Display something simple initially (i.e. returning a simple widget from your build method), then do the calculations after that, such as by clock scheduling them.

Your calculations will still block the gui in this case. You can work around this by doing them in a thread or by manually breaking them up into small pieces that can be sequentially scheduled.

It might be possible to update the gui by manually calling something like `Clock.tick()`, but I'm not sure if this will work right, and even if so it won't be able to display graphics before they have been initialised.

Comment: That depends on what these calculations actually are. Threads are almost certainly a reasonable solution, but the calculations might easily decompose into something that can be incrementally performed in a regular clock event.